# CSS Align text at top of flexbox 'column'

Tags: html, css, text-align

If there is a row of flex boxes each with text eg:

[Text1][Text2][text3] where the text size is bigger for each box how can I align the text to the top?

example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.t1 {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.t2 {
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.t3 {
  font-size: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="t1">Text1</div>
  <div class="t2">Text2</div>
  <div class="t3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

Align-vertical doesn't work...

Text has space above each item which gets bigger as text size gets bigger

Comment: You can try use `line-height` on text items